# How to generate good-looking line words?

Tags: comments

like this:

```
         __                                     __  
  ____  / /_     ____ ___  __  __   ____  _____/ /_ 
 / __ \/ __ \   / __ `__ \/ / / /  /_  / / ___/ __ \
/ /_/ / / / /  / / / / / / /_/ /    / /_(__  ) / / /
\____/_/ /_/  /_/ /_/ /_/\__, /    /___/____/_/ /_/ 
                        /____/
```

I found some tools, but they do not look good

Comment: Can you elaborate on this?  Have you tried some code to do this, but you encountered a problem?  Note that Stack Overflow is primarily for programming related questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are on Linux you can install `figlet`.

[this thread presents other tools](https://serverfault.com/a/93408/466502)

And if you want the simpler way, there's a lot of online generators just google "**ascii art generator**"